# Default Maven Project vs. Converted Maven Project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I had some project that used to be regular Java project in Eclipse.
now I wanted to convert it to Maven project. The thing I noticed is that, when I convert it's missing whole a lot of folders/packages that I would have had if I were to created the Maven project at the beginning.

plus, the ones missing are the ones matter the most (i.e. src/java(or test)/main scr/java(or test)/resource

if Eclipse provided this option, why it didn't fix this "issue" (I don't have enough knowledge to mark it as an issue, since I am not sure if it was intentional action)

I even tried Project -> Clean ; and (right click on the project) --> Maven --> Update Project

are we supposed to create those missing folders manually after we convert?

Thank you

Comment: How did you managed dependencies before? Missing folder could be not that important compared to that. Does the generated pom.xml have the correct dependencies?

Comment: @LMC: Thank you for your reply! It does have the pom.xml file, I didn't specifically check the default content of the pom file, as far as dependencies concerned, usually we download the dependencies based on what we are trying to do, right? (from your answer I am sensing all that "convert" does is to help us generate pom.xml file so that we can add dependencies, if that was what this is all about. then I will deal with that.